# OPCUA custom events

Tags: java, client-server, opc-ua, opc, unified-automation-sdk

Getting problem while adding the custom events to server node hierarchy in OPCUA server code(Prosys java sdk).

When subscribing to these custom events directly after expanding into Server node in UAExpert, I am able to receive the events, but as per the specifications it is supposed that even when we subscribe to parent node i.e., Server Node, in that case also we should receive the child node events which is the custom event node.
And I am not able to receive the child node events (custom event) when subscribing to the Server Node.
How to add these custom events under the Server node heirachy?

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: @ErezA.Korn - Using prosys java sdk 4.2.0